# How to hide default system error message

Tags: magento-1.9

I have implemented an observer `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` to be able to add **custom discounts** in certain cases without having to  create the coupon codes. So even if the coupon code is invalid, my custom coupon validation can add a discount.

Its working fine but what I want to do is hide the default error message

> "Coupon code X is not valid"

Only in cases where my custom validation is successful. I know I can edit `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` file but I don't want to edit core files and I don't want to hide the error message when my validation is not successful.